# Android futimes()

Tags: android, android-ndk, jni, c++

Есть такая в линуксе функция `futimes()`; Для изменения времени доступа в открытом файле. Под андроидом ее нет и заменить то в общем нечем. Собирал приличный по размерам проект, только этой функции и не нашлось.
Функция не особо то важна, сойдет и заглушка, но хочется узнать, где достать аналог. `utimes()` не подходит.

Comment: `File.setLastModified()` не подходит?

Comment: Во первых это java. А во вторых мне нужна системная функция без всяких классов.

Comment: Ну если вы пишете тег `jni` это дает мне право думать, что Java в проекте есть. Под NDK Java куски включить в общем то не проблема.

Comment: java только на стадии запуска. Я бы не хотел использовать java. Так же в futimes() передается id открытого файла. А в java я так понимаю файл придется еще раз открыть.